# Difficulty to enable a remote desktop connection to Ubuntu from Mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac, vnc, vncserver

I'm trying to perform a remote desktop connection to my Ubuntu system from Mac.

I had installed the vnc on ubuntu and trying to use Finder to connect.

The problem is I'm getting a error message:

`The software on the remote computer appears to be incompatible with this version of Screen Sharing.`

Somone knows how to solve this?

**Info**

Mac OS X 10.8.2

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Finder 10.8.1

vncserver (couldn't find it directly (no -v option available), but the man says `03 Mar 2005`)

Comment: VNC versions would be helpful as it sounds more like an application issue as opposed to the OS.  You may not be able to use finder.

Comment: @hydroparadise, I'm trying to get the vncserver version, but I couldn't yet... It hasn't a -v option. Anyway the man says `03 Mar 2005`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a significant difference between using `ssh -X` or the VNC system. With VNC you get a visual copy of the desktop on the remote system at that moment the VNC server was started. With `ss -X` you start a new X-session; it also requires a X-Windows system on the local computer. Because a Mac is basically a *nix system, this shouldn't be a problem.

So it depends how you want to setup your remote desktop session: see what's on the remote monitor or start a new session.

When using `ssh -X` you should check whether X-Windows forwarding is enabled on the remote computer. Check the file  /etc/ssh/ssh_config and your possible default settings for the entry  `ForwardX11` (it should be `yes` for this to work).

Then an important thing: once you are connected to the remote machine, all you have is a shell. If you want to see the desktop, start the Unity desktop (or KDE, or XFCE4) using the proper command. For instance for XFCE4 start
`xfce4-session`

Remember that running Unity implies a lot of heavy graphics work that needs to go over the SSH-line, so perhaps you can install XFCE4 along with Unity.

Another tip: exchange SSH key for login-less SSH :) Use `ssh-copy-id user@machine` and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run only one or two applications on the Ubuntu system, then you can use ssh with '-X' option.

```
ssh -X user@ubuntu
```

Then run browser etc on the Ubuntu's command line and it will become visible on your Mac. This will allow you to run any GUI application(like firefox) remotely from the Mac system.

On a side note, to find the version of vncserver you can run:

```
dpkg -l vncserver
```

or if the above doesn't work:

```
dpkg -l|grep vncserver
```

you also need to mention version of vnc client installed on Mac.